# How to group saved site passwords in iOS safari

Tags: ios, safari, password, google-chrome, login

I have multiple businesses and multiple site logins for each. On PC I can open Chrome browser, select a google account that I created for one of my businesses, and then I’m automatically logged in to all the sites for that business. Is there something similar to this in iOS safari or is there a browser app in iOS that can group saved passwords for multiple sites?

For example, let’s say I have two businesses and they each have their own RedBubble, Etsy and eBay accounts. When I open safari I’m automatically logged in to each sited with the login credentials for my 1st business. But now if I want to manage my 2nd business, I have logout and login to each site using my sending business credentials. Is there an easier way to do this similar to chrome in PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You refer to saved passwords in your title but I assume you mean saved cookies, not the Safari password manager.

Beginning with iOS 17 and macOS Sonoma - both currently available only in beta and not general release - Safari adds profile support.

Profiles in Safari allow a window to be designated as any number of arbitrary profiles, each with their own set of cookies. Logging into a website with one account in one profile will leave you logged out in other profiles.

If you **did** mean specifically the Password manager in Safari, then no there is no way to group them.